# White Space Appears when keyboard pop in screen Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scaffold

I am using single child scroll view scaffold under a scaffold and when keyboard appears a white space pops and hide the content behind it. I have tried setting resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, it solves my problem but singlechildscroll view doesn't work and I want single child scroll view to work as i have few contents behind keyboard.
[Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8HkH.png) [without opening keyboard] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbZTR.png)

I have tried setting resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, it solves my problem but singlechildscroll view doesn't work and I want single child scroll view to work as i have few contents behind keyboard.

Flutter Doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1992], locale en-IN)
Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at.\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
Visual Studio - develop for Windows
Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
Android Studio (version 2022.2)
VS Code (version 1.80.1)
Connected device (3 available)
Network resources`